# Overriding a method in an extension, Swift

Tags: swift, overriding, extension-methods, swift5

Since which version of Swift does the following code no longer build?

```swift
import Foundation

@objc class Class: NSObject {
  @objc func str() -> String {
    return "Hello, playground"
  }
}

class Subclass: Class {

}

extension Subclass {
  override func str() -> String {
    return "Hi"
  }
}
```

From my understanding, previous versions of Swift compiled this code with unexpected results. On Swift 5.1, it no longer builds.

Comment: Please don't tag all Swift versions and only use a specific version tag if your question is directly related to a change in a specific version. So only the `swift5` tag is valid, the 2,3 and 4 shouldn't have been added.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Dynamic modifier

You can do it using the `dynamic` modifier

```
@objc class Animal: NSObject {

    @objc dynamic func saySomething() {
        print("I am an Animal")
    }

}

@objc class Dog: Animal { }

extension Dog {

    override func saySomething() {
        print("I am a Dog")
    }

}

Dog().saySomething() // I am a Dog
```

> Tested with Swift 5.1.3

Comment: The question is not how to make it compile. The question is purely historical: "Since which version of Swift does the following code no longer [compile]?" The only possible answer is a version number.

Comment: @matt I think you are right. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: my understanding was, perhaps erroneously, that my posted override code used to compile because of my ignorance of the dynamic keyword

Answer (score 0):

as you can see here -> [Extensions documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) you can add new functionality but you can't override methods in extensions.

> NOTE
>
> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.

So you can't do it in Swift 5.1

Comment: This is different with obj-c though, especially with the `dynamic` modifier. The rule for `@objc` classes has been only been enforced recently.